# cant clone the source code in deepin 15,5

Tags: command-line, terminal, deepin

I am now using deepin 15,5 but, when I start to clone this project https://github.com/user23a/dde-dock ,via terminal using (git clone) command, an error massage appears to me and its shown bellow
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYChK.jpg

Comment: Please don't post image of text. It is likely to get downvoted on this site. Also please show what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I was trying to clone a project, but when I type this commend (git clone), an error appears to me and It was" fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists "

Comment: Do not put such important information in a comment only. Readers shall not be required to read the comments. Edit the question instead and add the information there.

Comment: @user (if that is your real name): your comment (above) describes what you did to *encounter* the problem.   Weijun Zhou asked you to show what you have tried to ***solve*** the problem.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself and format it as code with the `{}` icon in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

The repository only accepts key verification when cloned over ssh. Either modify the repository's setting  if you have access to, or clone over HTTPS.

To be more specific. I have successfully cloned the repository by running

```
git clone https://github.com/user23a/dde-dock.git
```

Comment: it's worth mentioning that for github.com, you can only use ssh cloning with a key if you have an account on github and have uploaded your **public** key to the site.  You can use a key for cloning public repos, but it's mostly useful for cloning private repos that are only accessible to specific users & groups.