# how can I open the project folder after cloning it with https using github

Tags: command-line, terminal, github, deepin

I am using deepin 15,5 but how can I know the repository folder after cloning it with https and the command was

`git clone`

Comment: What does `ls` give you? The cloned repo should be in a directory of the same name, you should know it from the HTTPS link from your `git clone` command

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a follow-up to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414081/86440),

```
cd dde-dock
```

will change to the cloned repository. It’s the last part of the cloned URL.